# nsclient++ map file entries for windows servers

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nsclient++

We use nagios to monitor our network. Has anyone found a sample map file containing entries that correspond to the services in nsclient++

Comment: Do you mean something other than what's covered in the sample config and the docs?

Answer (score -1):

i usually get the 4 main metrics for all windows boxes: cpu usage, uptime (for graphing), memory utilization, free space on drive c - via a cfg file in the etc/services folder, as follows below, and then capture particular windows performance counters through [something like I described on another answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/124440/nagios-terminal-services-check/127348#127348).

```
define service{
        use                     default_service
        hostgroup               windows-boxes
        service_description     C_Drive_Space
        check_command           check_nt!USEDDISKSPACE!-l c -w 80 -c 90
        }

define service{
        use                     default_service
        hostgroup               windows-boxes
        service_description     Memory_Usage
        check_command           check_nt!MEMUSE!-w 80 -c 90
        }

define service{
        use                     default_service
        hostgroup               windows-boxes
        service_description     CPU_Load
        check_command           check_nt!CPULOAD!-l 5,80,90
        }

define service{
        use                     default_service
        hostgroup               windows-boxes        service_description     Uptime
        check_command           check_nt!UPTIME
        }

define service{
        use                     default_service
        hostgroup               windows-boxes
        service_description     NSClient_Version
        check_command           check_nt!CLIENTVERSION
        }
```

the cool thing with the check_nt and check_nrpe is that you can easily deploy your own checks to windows boxes, even batch file scripts! make sure you encrypt and secure that connection by modifying the nsc.ini file. also, make sure your windows hosts only accept inbound connections from the nagios server(s) (also on the nsc.ini file).

Comment: These aren't map file entries. They are service commands.

Comment: Ok, I guess I don't understand what the RP means by "nsclient++ map entries". Care to clarify?